# primefaces 4 - how to create new dialog instance each time an event occur

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, jsf, primefaces

Is it possible to open a new dialog instance on the same button click event?

***For example :***

```
click -> open dialog
click again -> open a second dialog, keeping the first one opened
click again -> ... and so on
```

Comment: Why would you need such a thing, it's not recommend to have multiple visible dialogs in the same time. It is possible to do so depends on the full scenario that you have ...

Comment: @HatemAlimam in my case, the app will start an instance of ajaxtermJ (web-based terminal emulator) each time, and the user will need keep different instances. If the dialog is not the right tool, maybe I could try to open a new window (window.open()) but then browsers don't like popups. I've read something about creating dialog instances dynamically and add them to the DOM, but I'd like to ask first just in case there's some easier/more elegant way

Comment: Update your post with a sample dialog you would generate every time...

Comment: the new dialog will just point to a JSP with an iframe inside and a unique generated ID as a GET parameter

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a solution based on your requirement **(iframe)**

*xhtml*

```
    <h:form id="form">

        <div id="dialogs"></div>

        <p:commandButton value="New Terminal" 
                         update="dilaogContainer"
                         oncomplete="handleNewDialog()"/>

        <h:panelGroup id="dilaogContainer">
            <p:dialog id="#{bean.nextDialogId()}" height="300" width="300" >                     
                <iframe src="http://www.w3schools.com/" width="100%" height="100%"></iframe>
            </p:dialog>
        </h:panelGroup>

    </h:form>
```

*bean*

```
public String nextDialogId() {
    // Generate random id of 5 char
    return org.apache.commons.lang.RandomStringUtils.random(5, true, false);
}
```

*JS*

```
var dialogs = [];

function handleNewDialog() {
   newDialog = $(PrimeFaces.escapeClientId('form:dilaogContainer')).find(">:first-child");
   newDialog.appendTo("#dialogs");
   newDialogVar = getWidgetVar(newDialog.attr('id'));        
   newDialogVar.show();
   moveDialog(newDialogVar);
   dialogs.push(newDialogVar); 
}

function moveDialog(dialog) {
   if(dialogs.length > 0) {
       lastDialog = dialogs[dialogs.length -1];
       dialog.jq.css({'left' : lastDialog.jq.position().left+ 300 +'px'})
   } else {
       dialog.jq.css({'left' : '0px'})
   }
}

function getWidgetVar(id) {
   widgetName = 'widget_' + id.replace(/\:/g, '_');
   return window[widgetName];
}
```

On the button click we update our dialogContainer thus our dialog is updated and generated with a new ID. We take the generated Dialog outside the container by appending it into the dialogs div, show it, reposition it according to the other shown dialogs.

NOTE: please keep in mind that this approach is only valid in iframe cases, where our DOM tree is not synced with the JSF component tree.

It would be something like this.

[image: jsf dialogs]

Answer (score 0):

I can add a new dialog on demand just adding this code to the p:command event

```
UIComponent panelGroup = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().findComponent(":sm:yourSites");
Dialog dialog = new Dialog();
String id = "Sample"+System.currentTimeMillis();
dialog.setId(id );
dialog.setHeader(id);
dialog.setVisible(true);
dialog.setMinimizable(true);
dialog.setWidgetVar("W"+id);
panelGroup.getChildren().add(dialog);
this.dialogWidget = dialog.getWidgetVar();
```

and

```
<p:commandButton  icon="ui-icon-person" action="#{myMB.connect}" title="Connect" update=":sm:yourSites" oncomplete="#{myMB.dialogWidget}.show();">  
<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{site.name}" target="#{myMB.siteId}"  />  
</p:commandButton>
```

but then I've noticed that dialogs only live in the same page context, it's not the same as a new browser pop up window :-(

also, on the parent component refresh, opened dialogs come closed (they don't keep their size on resize)

so I think I can't avoid the window popup approach for this.